# Why delta connections are done when the motor is required to be operated at 220V?

Tags: motor, ac, delta, star

I am working with a tip dresser which is used for dressing the tip of the welding gun. A motor is used in that tip dresser which is used to rotate the cutter to dress the tip. There are two provisions for wiring the motor of the tip dresser one is when we want to power the motor using 400V we have to make STAR connections and if we want to operate it in 220v we need to connect it in DELTA.
So my question here is why STAR connection is chosen for 440V and why DELTA connection is required for 220v.

Comment: Short answer: because Y at 440V looks a lot like Δ-connected 220V as far as the individual windings are concerned. I don't have the energy to expand this out into more than a comment though.

Comment: The voltage between any two terminals on a wye-connection is spread between two windings, but the voltage between any one terminal on a delta-connection is all across one winding. So if your individual windings are the same, a wye connection can take more voltage.

Comment: If you have a phase voltage of 220 volts, then the line voltage will be 381 volts and not 400 volts or 440 volts.

Answer (score 1):

The tip dresser motor phases are wound for 220 V.

1. To run it on 3 x 220 V, the phases are to be delta-connected.

[image]

Since the line voltage is 220 V, each phase of the motor is fed 220 V.

2. To run it on 3 x 380 V, the phases are to be star-connected.

[image]

With a line voltage of 380 V, the phase voltage would be 220 V (380 / √3 = 220).

Thus each phase is still fed 220 V.